# Distribution of column of random orthogonal matrix

Tags: probability-distributions, orthonormal, svd

Suppose $O \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$ with $r < n$ is a random matrix whose distribution is uniform on the set of $r \times n$ matrices such that $O'O = I_r$.

Is is true that the columns of $O$, marginally, are uniformly distributed on the unit sphere? If so, how would one prove this? Clearly, this is not true of the joint distribution of the columns.

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: By "marginally", do you just mean the distribution of each column as elements of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Yes -- treating each column as a random variable, the distribution of $O$ itself tells about about the joint distribution, but I'm interested in the distribution of a single column.

Comment: This should certainly be uniform, and this follows from the fact that all of the distributions here are invariant under the usual (say, left) action of $O(n)$, which in particular is transitive. To this end, note that we can view the set of $r \times n$ matrices such that $O' O = I_r$ as a quotient $O(n) / O(r)$ and $S^{n - 1}$ as a quotient $O(n) / O(n - 1)$.

Comment: Do you have a suggested reference for this statement? I agree that it is true, but it would be nice to have a simple citation for this fact.

Comment: No, I'm not aware of one.